# Simulating click button on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to access a webpage, which has a text field and a "Go" button. In a loop I assign values to the text field and when I click Go, it should take me to another webpage.
The source looks like this for text field.

```
<td>
     <input name="ctl00$cphMyMasterCentral$ucSearch$txtNumber" type="text" value="40010" id="ctl00_cphMyMasterCentral_ucSearch_txtNumber" disabled="disabled" style="width:200px;" />
</td>
```

for Go button

```
<a id="ctl00_cphMyMasterCentral_ucSearch_lbtnSearch" class="submit" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMyMasterCentral$ucSearch$lbtnSearch", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Go</a>
```

This is what I have in C# code

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mainURL);
 request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC EA 2; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3)";
 request.Timeout = 100000;
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 WebBrowser b =new WebBrowser();
 string html = wc.DownloadString(mainURL);
 b.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphMyMasterCentral_ucSearch_txtNumber").InnerText = "100";
 b.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphMyMasterCentral_ucSearch_lbtnSearch").InvokeMember("click");
```

I got an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any tips on how to handle it, thanks

Comment: You have not navigated anywhere on your WebBrowser. If you try using Webbrowser b to navigate to the page you want you may have more luck. Also you might want to check out Watin. It's web browsing add on for .Net which makes what you are trying to do much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a WebClient to grab the html but the WebBrowser never knows about it, so of course the webbrowser is not going to like it when you tell him to get an element by ID isn't it? To do this you do not need the webclient class at all. Just look up WebBrowser.Navigate and you will find the thing you need